# Do other living creatures besides Insaan and jin pray to the Almighty?

Tags: life, ibadah, aqidah

Does other living creatures besides Insaan (human) and [jin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn) pray to the Almighty?

Is there any verse in the Al Quran about this topic?

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help). It is not clear from your question what misconception you have. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 5):

There are several Quranic verses to the effect that all things, living and non-living, worship Allah through prostration and glorification.

> [Quran 22:18](https://quran.com/22/18) Do you not see that to Allah prostrates whoever is in
>   the heavens and whoever is on the earth and the sun, the moon, the
>   stars, the mountains, the trees, the moving creatures and many of the
>   people? But upon many the punishment has been justified. And he whom
>   Allah humiliates - for him there is no bestower of honor. Indeed,
>   Allah does what He wills.
>
> [Quran 16:48-50](https://quran.com/16/48-50) Have they not considered what things Allah has
>   created? Their shadows incline to the right and to the left,
>   prostrating to Allah, while they are humble. And to Allah prostrates
>   whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth of creatures,
>   and the angels [as well], and they are not arrogant. They fear their
>   Lord above them, and they do what they are commanded.
>
> [Quran 17:44](https://quran.com/17/44) The seven heavens and the earth and whatever is in
>   them exalt Him. And there is not a thing except that it exalts [ Allah
>   ] by His praise, but you do not understand their [way of] exalting.
>   Indeed, He is ever Forbearing and Forgiving.
>
> [Quran 55:5-6](https://quran.com/55/5-6) The sun and the moon [move] by precise calculation, And the stars and trees prostrate.

Though the mode of worship is different for different things. The sun and stars prostrate by their orbiting, the trees and animals prostrate by casting their shadows and doing what Allah created them to do. The animals do tasbeeh in their own tongues and minds.

Comment: It can be regarded as a helpful true answer, especially by using Quranic verses. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Islamic though of prayer all creations of Allah including both living praise Him. Which can also mean that they work within their bounds and according their appointed cycles.

Only humans have been given the ability to obey or disobey.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please provide your references that support your answer.